# What are the physical effects of a non-zero Torsion tensor?

Tags: general-relativity

In my experience of GR the torsion tensor is typically taken to vanish, but I believe this is more or less for simplicity than anything else.

What does the torsion tensor *do*?  What physical effects would it manifest?  Do it's components get nice explanations? [For example, the $(i,j)^{th}$ component of the Stress-Energy tensor is the flux of $i$-momentum in the $j$-direction.]

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103576/

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27746/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/192230/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103576/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/315698/2451  and links therein.