# Why does general relativity assume that the torsion is equal to zero?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, differential-geometry, geodesics, equivalence-principle

I do not understand why the torsion is set equal to zero in the general theory of relativity. The geodesics would be the same. Is there even a way to test it?

Pg 250 from the 2017 edition of MTW says

> $\nabla$ is said to be a "symmetric" or "torsion-free" covariant
> derivative when
> $\nabla_{\mathbf{u}}\mathbf{v}-\nabla_{\mathbf{v}}\mathbf{u} = [\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}]$. Other types of covariant derivatives, as
> studied by mathematicians, have no relevance for any gravitation
> theory based on the equivalence principle.

but I don't know what does this have to do with the equivalence principle.

Comment: Autoparallel geodesics would not be the same though. Moreover, allowing for torsion opens up for more general theories of gravity beyond GR (such as Einstein-Cartan). It is a choice at the end of the day, but the dynamics of the theories are different.

Comment: There is no experimental evidence so far that including torsion is necessary. Therefore, by Occam’s Razor, it is excluded. There is no point in making a theory more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27746/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103576/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/362319/2451